# Object of class PDOStatement could not convert to string

Tags: pdo

I changed my mysqli connection to PDO statment so i have to much error on my page this is the my code pls help us

.
.
.

```
if ($fn && $ln && $e && $p) { // If everything's OK...

    // Make sure the email address is available:
    //$q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$e'";
    $q = $dbc->query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$e'");
    $q->execute(array($e));
    $r = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 0) { // Available.

        // Create the activation code:
        $a = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

Comment: You should post the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code converted to PDO.

```
// Make sure the email address is available:
$q = $dbc->query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email=?");
$q->execute(array($e));
$r = $q->fetchColumn();

if (!$r) { // Available.
    // Create the activation code:
    $a = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

Three things has been corrected

1. You have to always use a placeholder tp represent a variable in the query.
2. To get a single value from the result, `fetchColumn` have to be used instead of `fetchAll`
3. No need for the manual reporting, as PDO can report its errors automatically, if confugired properly, as described in [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) I wrote